# Does Gallagher have a twin brother?

Tags: television

It has been widely reported that [Leo Anthony Gallagher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallagher_%28comedian%29) (the comedian who likes to smash watermelons with a large mallet) has a twin brother named Ron who tours the country and impersonates his brother. His act has been known as "Gallagher Too" or "Gallagher Two".

Supposedly, Ron and Leo got into a legal trademark violation dispute over the "Sledge-O-Matic" routine made popular by Leo. However, [in the interviews with Ron and Leo](http://www.people.com/people/archive/article/0,,20131265,00.html), something seems a little fishy. Here are some quotes:

From Ron:

> Leo pretty much raised me, since both my parents worked

Later, from Leo:

> I was never around my brother at all [...] He wasn't a part of my life.

This made me skeptical that this relationship could be an elaborate joke/hoax/performance put on by Gallagher to gain publicity similar to what Joaquin Phoenix did with the movie "I'm Still Here".

Does Gallagher have a twin or is it a hoax?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, Leo Gallagher does not have a twin brother, Ron.

**He has a *younger brother*, Ron.**

Both the referenced Wikipedia page and the interview page explain that.

Attorney, [Greg Everts](http://www.quarles.com/greg_everts/), of Quarles & Brady documents the court-case details:

> Leo Gallagher a/k/a “Gallagher” and Sold Out Shows, Inc. v. Ron Gallagher et al., Case No. 99-75657 (Eastern District of Michigan). Counsel for comedian-plaintiff in suit for trademark infringement, Lanham Act false advertising, unfair competition, and violation of right of publicity. Obtained preliminary injunction and settlement that included permanent injunctive relief.

Given the intrinsic difficulty in hoaxing a court to be a party on both sides of a dispute, the lack of motive to do so and the speculative nature of the original question, I consider this sufficient evidence to dismiss the claim that Ron and Leo Gallagher are the same person.

Comment: When I originally researched this, I looked around for official documentation of the court case, but couldn't find it. Thanks! +1

Comment: Actually it seems you partially confirmed the myth that there was a brother that went around impersonating the more successful brother though.